# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable perlin_noise error

Tags: python, perlin-noise, ursina

I'm making game in python ursina perlin_noise and i got this error

Code:

```
noise = perlin_noise(octaves=1,seed=int(randrange(99,111)))
```

imported things:

```
from perlin_noise import perlin_noise
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your import should be:

`from perlin_noise import PerlinNoise`

and then your code should be:

`noise = PerlinNoise(octaves=1,seed=int(randrange(99,111)))`

Comment: i tried this and i got error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyCraft_tut_22.py", line 7, in <module>
    from perlin_noise import PerlinNoise
ImportError: cannot import name 'PerlinNoise' from 'perlin_noise' (C:\Users\usman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\perlin_noise\__init__.py)`

Comment: Are you using this perlin_noise Python library?:

https://pypi.org/project/perlin-noise/1.8/

Comment: no i type this and i got requierment already satisfied

Comment: Please could you try the following command:

`python3 -m pip list` 

and see which version of perlin_noise is installed.